# how do you force rendering of the upload template in jquery fileupload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

i'm using jquery fileupload by blueimp.  after an upload has completed successfully, i have a case where i may need to mark the file as an error.

how can i force re-rendering of the row?  i'm using the UI widget and the default templates supplied with the plugin.

i see in jquery.fileupload-ui.js a _renderUpload function but it's private.  i mark the file as an error in the example below, but have to cause a re-render to happen for the row to be rendered in the browser as an error.

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    data.files[0].error = true;
    // what do i need to here to force re-rendering? 
    //how do i get access to the widget instance and how can i force a re-render?
}
```

Comment: This seems like a little bit of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but when it comes to blueimp's file uploader, the first thing you do when trying to add new functionality to it is throwing all the code through the window and writing your own uploader script from scratch. Not being pessimist, but that thing is just plainly terrible to add new functionality from what I remember. I wish the best of luck for you in case you stick with it.

Comment: it's not an xy problem and adding new code isn't that bad .. i just need to know how to call a private function of a javascript widget, as i don't have much experience with javascript yet.

Comment: Seems like you just answered your own question. You can't call a `private` function, that is, if you mean a function declared through function declaration inside the constructor. You can only call public methods, or create a privileged function that bridges to the private function.

Comment: you somewhat answered it, i didn't.  but after more research i see that function privacy in javascript is by convention only.  i'd rather find a way to extend the plugin and write my own privileged function to do it properly, so if you can tell me how to do that i'd be happy to mark this as answered by you.

Comment: Sorry man, I've had my struggles with blueimp in the past already and I'm running late for university atm, but maybe later I can update my local repository and check if there's an easy way to do that.

Comment: Here's a simple and nice read about private/privileged/public functions in JS as well: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html